# Write access violation при записи в динамический массив C++

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Здравствуйте!
Есть следующая проблема. Есть класс Упражнение_1 для домашней работы, в котором должны быть функции создания и инициализации динамического массива. Функции из описания класса:

```
public:

int Exercise_1:: createArray()
{
    int size_of_new_arr;

    cout << " Enter the size of the array: ";
    cin >> size_of_new_arr;

    array_ptr = new int[size_of_new_arr];

    return size_of_new_arr;
}

void Exercise_1::initializeArray(int* arrFI, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        *(arrFI + i) = rand() % 100;
    }
}
```

Указатель и переменная в заголовочном файле:

```
public:
int* array_ptr;
int array_size;
```

В таком виде все работает нормально, Упражнение_1 корректно отрабатывает. Но если я переписываю первую функцию в следующем виде, то есть принимающую указатель из заголовочного файла как аргумент

```
public:

int Exercise_1:: createArray(int* arrForCreate) // << Принимает указатель 
{
    int size_of_new_arr;

    cout << " Enter the size of the array: ";
    cin >> size_of_new_arr;

    arrForCreate = new int[size_of_new_arr]; // << Выделяет  память

// Дальше ничего не меняется
    return size_of_new_arr;
}

void Exercise_1::initializeArray(int* arrFI, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        *(arrFI + i) = rand() % 100;
    }
}
```

и потом вызываю ее

```
Exercise_1 exercise_1;

exercise_1.array_size = exercise_1.createArray(exercise_1.array_ptr); // Создаю массив
exercise_1.initializeArray(exercise_1.array_ptr, exercise_1.array_size);
```

то я получаю ошибку

Exception thrown: write access violation.

arrFI was 0x1110112.

Помогите разобраться что к чему. Вроде же я кардинально ничего не меняю, пытаюсь инициализировать по сути один и тот же указатель. Я хочу использовать эти функции в другом классе для создания и инициализации другого динамического массива, поэтому нужно, чтобы функция принимала указатель как параметр. Заранее спасибо!

П.С. Стаж С++ около 2.5 месяца, я в самом начале пути и пока очень мало знаю, учитывайте это при ответах

Comment: Ваше `public:`, одиноко болтающееся в приведенном коде, как бы намекает, что вы делаете определения данных методов внутри определения класса. Если это так, то при определении метода класса внутри определения самого класса запрещается использовать квалифицированное имя метода, т.е. `Exercise_1::createArray`. Имя метода должно быть неквалифицированным, т.е. просто `createArray`.

Comment: Нет, `public` я написал в приведенном коде чтобы показать, что в определении класса эти методы являются `public`. В определении класса они и называются просто `createArray` и `initializeArray` соответственно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычная стандартная ошибка.

```
int Exercise_1:: createArray(int* arrForCreate) // << Принимает указатель 
{
...
    arrForCreate = new int[size_of_new_arr]; // << Выделяет  память
}
```

Итак, вы изменили `arrForCreate` - локальную **копию** указателя, переданного в функцию-член. Указатель-оригинал от этого не изменился...

Передавайте его как ссылку:

```
int Exercise_1:: createArray(int* &arrForCreate)
```

И еще... Эти ваши функции - они для чего предназначены? чтобы работать с данными объекта? тогда зачем передавать их как параметры?

```
exercise_1.array_size = exercise_1.createArray(exercise_1.array_ptr);
```

Ваш `createArray()` должен работать со своими данными-членами:

```
void Exercise_1::createArray()
{
    cout << " Enter the size of the array: ";
    cin >> array_size;
    delete[] array_ptr;
    array_ptr = new int[array_size]; 
}
```

И вызываться просто и незатейливо:

```
exercise_1.createArray();
```

Естественно, в конструкторе `array_ptr` должен быть корректно инициализирован.

Comment: Спасибо, со ссылкой все заработало.  Я написал в вопросе - я хочу, чтобы я мог использовать эти функции для создания такого же массива в объекте другого класса,  чтобы не писать в том другом классе точно такие же функции.  Тренируюсь так сказать. Я инициализирую array_ptr в конструкторе значением NULL, не знаю насколько это корректно.  Одно мне непонятно - почему для функции выделения памяти надо передавать ссылку, а для функции инициализации нормально работает простой указатель?

Comment: Тогда - *чтобы я мог использовать эти функции для создания такого же массива в объекте другого класса* - делайте ее статической функцией. Значение `NULL` вполне нормально, только в новом стандарте принято писать `nullptr`. При инициализации вы **не** меняете значение указателя.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения. До статических функций я еще не добрался, надо почитать, мы и классы-то проходить будем только через месяц-полтора, это самостоятельная работа так сказать). Буду разбираться.

Comment: Статическая функция-член не привязана к конкретному объекту (не работает с конкретными данными). Грубо - можно рассматривать, как свободную функцию, но с именем, предваренным именем класса и `::`. Вобщем, когда дойдете - разберетесь. Удачи!